# GCP How do I restrict requests to my API Gateway to only being accepted from 1 domain for security concerns?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cors, cross-domain, google-api-gateway

I have a GCP Cloud Function in a web app. I initially ran this by requiring authentication through a service account. I ran my app locally by authenticating with my service account's json file credentials. I will soon by deploying this app to a third party VPS server. I don't want to upload my service account credentials to a third party VPS so I set up an API Gateway. This works without requiring my credentials. My config file for the API Gateway looks like this:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: api-gateway
  description: API Gateway
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /v1/hello:
    get:
      summary: Hi Service
      operationId: hello-v1
      x-google-backend:
        address: <CLOUD_RUN_URL>
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
```

I just run `curl https://{gatewayId}-{hash}.{region_code}.gateway.dev/v1/hello` with my correct values replacing the placeholders and my cloud function actually ran without requiring any credentials.

At first I was glad that it worked, but then it occurred to me that I'm just trading 1 vulnerability with another. I can now call a function without authenticating lol. So is there at least a way to only allow my cloud function to be called through my api url when it is accessed from a particular caller domain. That way only my VPS could call the function through this link? I don't want to do this with a cors policy in my function because the function would technically still run and therefore run up my GCP bill.

Comment: I wonder if you've found solution.